# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: ajax, web-services

Currently im doing an asp.net website where im trying to get data from the webservice and display the data retrieved to the table. Below is the ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/CaregiverService.asmx/createJsDataTable",
data: "{}",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (json) {
    console.log(json);
    console.log(json.d.aaData);
    $('#nursingHomeTable').dataTable({
        "aaData": json.d.aaData,
    });
},
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            }    
});
</script>
```

For the webservice

```
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public JsonDataTable createJsDataTable()
        {

        JsonDataTable jsDT = new JsonDataTable();

        List<object> vl = new List<object>();
        vl.Add("value 1");
        vl.Add("value 2");
        vl.Add("value 3");
        vl.Add("value 4");
        jsDT.add_Row(vl);

        return jsDT;
       }
```

Have been getting that error when i inspect the element but still dont get wheres the error. I have clicked the `http://localhost:2179/CaregiverService.asmx/createJsDataTable` from the inspect element in google chrome and it works fine. Hoping someone could help me solve it :x

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fix your problem or not, but I was pretty sure that Asp.net webservices take only from the POST Method by default. So try changing type to POST.

OR

Set try setting this up in your receiving end in the webservice

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
```

OR

in your web.config 
try this

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Comment: Okay I get its a good idea to post links to relevant stackoverflow posts, but why did you downvote my answer? Was it unclear, inaccurate, or down right wrong? What could I do to improve it and make it up to snuff?

Comment: You said "I was pretty sure that Asp.net webservices take only from the POST Method" which that post proved wrong. Now that you added some useful information, it might be a better help.

Comment: I apologize, Its not that they only take POST, its that they take POST by default unless you configure them otherwise.